# Is it possible to change the glass color only for my own forms?

Tags: windows, delphi, color-scheme, aero-glass

I would like to create my application forms in the color independent from the user's color settings of the Aero. Is it possible to colorize my forms with the selected color without affecting the user's settings ?

This I want to do only for the Windows Aero colors.

Thanks

Comment: I just noticed that you can `DrawRect` in the `OnPaint` event of form to alter the colour of a region of glass. [It even looks OK.](http://privat.rejbrand.se/glassycolour.png) I fear that this 'hack' depends on undocumented assumptions, however... It might not work in the next version of Windows...

Comment: @Andreas, what is `DrawRect` ?

Comment: Sorry, meant `FillRect`.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks, good tip! I've sent you some reward :)

Comment: Thanks! It even gave me a new badge!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that, the glass composition color is system wide. As workaround you can  draw a 32 bits bitmap of a solid color over the form using the [Windows.AlphaBlend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.